# Given $p,q$ odd primes, prove that if $\gcd(a,pq)=1$ then $a^{\operatorname{lcm} (p-1,q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Given $p,q$ odd primes, prove that if $\gcd(a,pq)=1$ then $a^{\operatorname{lcm} (p-1,q-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$

**What I am thinking:**

I know by Fermat's that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ and also $a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$. I need to combine them somehow. Should I use the chinese remainder theorem?

In which case what is the inverse of $p \bmod q$ and vise versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem as you have suggested.  But the easiest way is to use it to **check** your answer, not to **find** the answer.  Let's write $l={\rm lcm}(p-1,q-1)$.

We have
$$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p\ ,$$
and since $l$ is a multiple of $p-1$,
$$a^l\equiv1\pmod p\ .$$
Similarly
$$a^l\equiv1\pmod q\ .$$
Therefore $x=a^l$ is a solution of the simultaneous congruences
$$x\equiv1\pmod p\ ,\quad x\equiv1\pmod q\ ;$$
but by CRT this system has a unique solution modulo $pq$, and $x=1$ is clearly a solution, so we have $a^l\equiv1\pmod{pq}$.

Answer (score 1):

We need to assume that $p$ and $q$ are *distinct*.

Let $L$ be our lcm. Since $p-1$ divides $L$, we have $a^L\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Similarly, $a^L\equiv 1\pmod{q}$. Thus $p$ divides $a^L-1$ and $q$ divides $a^L-1$. Since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, it follows that $pq$ divides $a^L-1$.

Comment: You are welcome. We are not really using the CRT, just simple facts about divisibility.